# Best practice: Nested subscriptions to receive user data?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm developing an Ionic 2 mobile app using Firebase as backend. With Firebase, some authentication data is stored with firebase automatically (currently logged in user's id, email and password). The other user data (name, address, ...) is stored in my Firebase database.

To get the currently logged in user's data, I have to subscribe to Firebase's auth methode first. Using angularfire2 I do the following:

```
this.af.auth.subscribe(data => {
  ... // data.uid gives me the user's id
}
```

Now I know the user's id and can subscribe to my Firebase database to get the other user data by doing:

```
this.af.database.object('/users/'+userId).subscribe( userData => {
   ...
}
```

If I combine both it's a nested subscription looking like this:

```
this.af.auth.subscribe(data => {
   this.af.database.object('/users/'+user.uid).subscribe( userData => {
       ...
   }
}
```

This works, however, it doesn't feel right to have two nested subscriptions. How do you guys deal with this? What would be a "best practice approach" here?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by Rxjs [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) operator

```
this.af.auth.subscribe(user=> {
   this.af.database.object('/users/'+user.uid).subscribe( userData => {
       ...
   }
}
```

to

```
this.af.auth.mergeMap(user=>this.af.database.object('/users/'+user.uid))
    .subscribe(userData){
        ...
    }
```

To answer your question, mergeMap is used to avoid nested subscription and remaining stuff is your app specific logic.